# Dockerfile RUN command taking a lot of disk space

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile with this RUN command:

```
RUN ln -s /usr/java/jdk1.5.0_22 /usr/java/java-5-sun && \
ln -s /usr/java/jdk1.5.0_22 /usr/java/jdk1.5 && \
ln -s /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45 /usr/java/java-6-sun && \
ln -s /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45 /usr/java/jdk1.6 && \
ln -s /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79 /usr/java/java-7-sun && \
ln -s /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79 /usr/java/jdk1.7 && \
ln -s /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60 /usr/java/java-8-sun && \
ln -s /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60 /usr/java/jdk1.8 && \
chown -R user.root /usr/java
```

but, as I see from the history, it take a lot of disk space!!

```
/bin/sh -c ln -s /usr/java/jdk1.5.0_22 /usr/j   1.019 GB
```

Do you know why?

Comment: What are you showing us here? where did the `1.019 GB` come from?

Comment: Why do you want those many jdk's? why not to have the required version which might condense the disk size?

Comment: @yaron is the output from the "docker history command"

Comment: @Rao We have projects written in different jdk version, so at the moment we need to keep all the necessary version for compiling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you're wondering why this specific image layer is 1 GiB in size when all you did was creating a few new symlinks. Correct? (Why four different JDKs are large in size should be self-explanatory).

Key is the `chown user.root /usr/java` statement. I strongly suspect that this statement causes the files for which the permissions were changed (i.e. probably the entire `/usr/java` directory) to be added again to this layer in the image.

You can verify this behaviour with a very simple example. Consider the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN echo foo > /tmp/bar
RUN useradd foo
RUN chown foo /tmp/bar
```

Now build this image with `docker build` and then inspect it with `docker history <image-id>`:

```
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
fdd96781f94f        5 seconds ago       /bin/sh -c chown foo /tmp/bar                   4 B                 
7237dbee1999        6 seconds ago       /bin/sh -c useradd foo                          330.3 kB            
69ed7323a0b0        6 seconds ago       /bin/sh -c echo foo > /tmp/bar                  4 B                 
17b6a9e179d7        5 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["/bin/bash"]             0 B                 
b0c2dfa2701f        5 months ago        /bin/sh -c sed -i 's/^#\s*\(deb.*universe\)$/   1.895 kB            
202e40f8bb3a        5 months ago        /bin/sh -c rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*          0 B                 
acb8e44f43fa        5 months ago        /bin/sh -c set -xe   && echo '#!/bin/sh' > /u   701 B               
487bffc61de6        5 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:ffc85cfdb5e66a5b4f   120.8 MB
```

Use the ID of the topmost layer (`/bin/sh -c chown foo /tmp/bar`) and look for this ID in `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/<ID>...` (assuming you're using AUFS as storage driver):

```
$ find /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/fdd96781f94feee4a6db44b11f7f9411c52238458ceeef202b2203e77b9970f4
/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/fdd96781f94feee4a6db44b11f7f9411c52238458ceeef202b2203e77b9970f4
/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/fdd96781f94feee4a6db44b11f7f9411c52238458ceeef202b2203e77b9970f4/tmp
/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/fdd96781f94feee4a6db44b11f7f9411c52238458ceeef202b2203e77b9970f4/tmp/bar
```

As you can see, changing the permissions of a file during the build process causes it to be added again in the next image layer. Changing the permissions of all your Java SDKs, causes all of them (with ~1 GiB in size) to be added to an additional image layer.

Comment: Yes, you get the point. I suspected that the problem was that, now I'm sure. Thanks!